# Interpolação no angular não atualiza

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Estou aprendendo angular e estou com uma dificuldade, o programa é bem simples tem um textInput e um paragrafo, oque se digitar no textInput deve aparecer no paragrafo.

```
onKeyUp(evento: any){
     this.valorAtual = evento.target.value ;
     console.log(evento.target.value)
  }
```

```
         <input type="text"  (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"   />

         <p> {{valorAtual}}</p>
```

O problema é que as vezes funciona, outras vezes não as vezes só atualiza uma vez não sei oque estou fazendo de errado.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri o erro, não era no código, meu navegador ficava traduzindo a pagina e quando eu colocava um texto nada haver ele não conseguia traduzir.

Answer (score 0):

Bastava você usar [(ngModel)]="valorAtual" no textInput, que já iria aparecer no parágrafo, sem a necessidade do evento.